# I accidentally deleted my home folder and Trash bin (Ubuntu 12.04)

Tags: unity, nautilus, delete, trash

I accidentally deleted the *Files* folders from `/usr/share/application`, and now I can't open the Trash bin from the unity Panel. and I can't open any of my folders from the Dash.

Also, my home folder is missing from the Panel (or Launcher). I ran `gksu nautilus /usr/share/application/` and deleted a couple of *Files* folders by mistake.

When I open the Trash bin from a window, the folders I deleted are not in there so I can't restore them.

Comment: Please don't edit the title to include it's solved, but instead, mark the correct answer as such. I invite you to take a tour to see how this site works. http://askubuntu.com/tour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this command:

```
echo '[Desktop Entry]
Name=Files
Comment=Access and organize files
Keywords=folder;manager;explore;disk;filesystem;
Exec=nautilus --new-window %U
Icon=system-file-manager
Terminal=false
Type=Application
StartupNotify=true
OnlyShowIn=GNOME;Unity;
Categories=GNOME;GTK;Utility;Core;
MimeType=inode/directory;application/x-gnome-saved-search;
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Bugzilla=GNOME
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Product=nautilus
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Component=general
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Version=3.6.3
Actions=Window;
X-Unity-IconBackgroundColor=#af4853
X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=nautilus

[Desktop Action Window]
Name=Open a New Window
Exec=nautilus --new-window
OnlyShowIn=Unity;' | sudo tee /usr/share/applications/nautilus.desktop
```

then

```
sudo chmod o+x /usr/share/applications/nautilus.desktop
```

Comment: Okay I Think I Fixed It I Did: gksu nautilus /usr/share/applications to open a folder, then i navigated to /root/.local/share/Trash and moved nautilus.desktop to /usr/share/applications. Now The Only Problem Is My Home Folder On The Launcher Is Called CD/DVD Creator. How Do I Rename It?

Answer (score 0):

Also try `sudo apt-get --reinstall install nautilus`.

This should reinstall Nautilus, and the removed file.

@minerz029 's answer should work if you can run `nautilus` in terminal.

Comment: Okay I Think I Fixed It I Did: gksu nautilus /usr/share/applications to open a folder, then i navigated to /root/.local/share/Trash and moved nautilus.desktop to /usr/share/applications. Now The Only Problem Is My Home Folder On The Launcher Is Called CD/DVD Creator. How Do I Rename It?